# How to describe or visualize a multiple linear regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization, presentation

I'm trying to fit a multiple linear regression model to my data with couple of input parameters, say 3.

\begin{align}
F(x) &= Ax_1 + Bx_2 + Cx_3 + d  \tag{i}  \\
&\text{or}  \\
F(x) &= (A\ B\ C)^T (x_1\ x_2\ x_3) + d  \tag{ii}
\end{align}

How do I explain and visualize this model?  I could think of the following options:

1. Mention the regression equation as described in $(i)$ (coefficients, constant) along with standard deviation and then a residual error plot to show the accuracy of this model.
2. Pairwise plots of independent and dependent variables, like this:

   [image]
3. Once the coefficients are known, can the data points used to obtain equation $(i)$ be condensed to their real values. That is, the training data have new values, in the form $x$ instead of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $\ldots$ where each of independent variable is multiplied by its respective coefficient.  Then this simplified version can be visually shown as a simple regression as this:

   [image]

I'm confused on this in spite of going through appropriate material on this topic. Can someone please explain to me how to "explain" a multiple linear regression model and how to visually show it.

Comment: What is the purpose of your document and who are the audiences? I'd start from getting similar articles and look for some examples on how they are done in your own field. I am more familiar with biomedical literature and most of the time, we just use a table. Illustrations are more often seen when the authors try to explain an interaction.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, this is in computer science domain, however I think this is a generic rather than restricted to a particular domain. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm... though question. I'd say the only generic part, for me, is don't show more than you should, and make sure the components to be emphasized really get emphasized. Even in just my field, I have seen all three options. 1) tabulating the results is the most common, followed by 3), but mostly the form of plotting predicted outcome, and then 2). But for 2), I'd use what @gregory_britten suggested: use adjusted X instead of each individual X.

Comment: use distribution plot....
look at the distribution of the fitted values that result from the model and compare it to the distribution of the actual values.

Comment: I know this is from years ago, but if you revisit here, could you post the data? Then people would have something to work with to show different possibilities.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My favorite way of showing the results of a basic multiple linear regression is to first fit the model to normalized (continuous) variables. That is, z-transform the $X$s by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, then fit the model and estimate the parameters. When the variables are transformed in this way, the estimated coefficients are 'standardized' to have unit $\Delta Y/\Delta sd(X)$. In this way, the distance the coefficients are from zero ranks their relative 'importance' and their CI gives the precision. I think it sums up the relationships rather well and offers a lot more information than the coefficients and p.values on their natural and often disparate numerical scales. An example is below:

[image]

**EDIT**: Another possibility is to use an 'added variable plot' (i.e. plot the partial regressions). This gives another perspective in that it shows the bivariate relations between $Y$ and $X_i$ AFTER THE OTHER VARIABLES ARE ACCOUNTED FOR. For example, the partial regressions of $Y \sim X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ would give bivariate relations between $X_i$ against the residuals of $Y$ after regressing against the other two terms. You would go on to do this for each variable. Function `avPlots()` from library `car` gives these plots from a fitted `lm` object. An example is below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @gregory_britten for this information. The problem I have at hand has 8 independent variables. Do you think the 'added variable plots' would be reasonable for large number of input variables?

Comment: In line with the idea of the first plot,  if working in R,  I suggest looking at the RMS package which makes all of this easy.  The nice thing is that one can ask for meaningful step changes in the covariance,  thus avoiding the need to standardize.

Comment: @suzanne Yes definitely. The added variable plot gives you two dimensional perspectives for any number of variables. It may be particularly revealing in higher dimensions. One often finds revealing patterns in the residuals which were not at all obvious in the observed Y.

Comment: I don't quite understand the X1|X2&X3 notation in this context.I know how it is used in regards to probabilities, but I can't quite understand what it is saying here

Comment: @Casebash It is the partial regression on X1, given X2 and X3 are in the model

Comment: Very helpful! I used the forestplot R package to make something similar to the first graph.

Answer (score 2):

Since they all have to do with explaining the contributors for cirrhosis, have you tried doing a bubble/circle chart and use color to indicate the different regressors and circle radius to indicate relative impact upon cirrhosis?

I'm referring here to a Google chart type that looks like this:[image]

And on an unrelated note, unless I'm reading your plots wrong, I think you have some redundant regressors in there. Wine is already a liquor so if those two are separate regressors it doesn't make sense to keep both of them, if your goal is to explain the incidence of cirrhosis.

Answer (score 2):

@gregory_britten 's answer was exactly what I was looking for.  I figured I would share my implementation in python using pandas, matplotlib, and statsmodels.

```
X_norm = X4.copy() # This is a pd.Dataframe of the independent variables
X_norm = (X_norm - X_norm.mean()) / X_norm.std()
res_norm = sm.OLS(y_log, sm.add_constant(X_norm)).fit()

to_include = res_norm.params[res_norm.pvalues < 0.05][1:].sort_values() # get only those with significant pvalues
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,6), dpi=100)
ax.scatter(to_include, range(len(to_include)), color="#1a9988", zorder=2)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(to_include)), to_include.index) # label the y axis with the ind. variable names
ax.set_xlabel("Proportional Effect")
ax.set_title("Strength of Relationships")

# add the confidence interval error bars
for idx, ci in enumerate(res_norm.conf_int().loc[to_include.index].iterrows()):
    ax.hlines(idx, ci[1][0], ci[1][1], color="#eb5600", zorder=1, linewidth=3)

plt.axline((0,0), (0,1), color="#eb5600", linestyle="--") # add a dashed line at 0.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The visualization you show in 3 (scatter diagram of actual value against predicted value) is a good one. It can be used for any regressor. In this case, the example you show helps confirm the assumption of linearity, since the points are scattered above and below the line throughout the range.

Another assumption you have made is a lack of interaction among the factors. If you want to test that, then a good visualization is a scatter diagram of x_i against x_j, where the points are coloured by the size of the error in the prediction. Pairwise interactions among the xs will be revealed by patterns in the colours.